# Random next slide with fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

Has anyone managed to do it? I am building a project with fullpage.js and the client wants to have random pages showed at some point. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Too broad. You'll be lucky if anyone answers you.

Comment: @alvaro I wanted to see if anyone has done it. Basicly I just need an idea how to do the random slide pick.

Comment: This looks more a backend question than a front end one anyway.

Comment: @Alvaro Do you have any idea how to modify your fullpage.js in order to go to random next slide on scroll ?

Comment: as I said, this is more a backend task than a front end one. You should better deal with it on the server side.

Comment: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/dist/jquery.fullpage.js

Take a look at its source code, the `scrollPage` function seem to be helpful ;)